# Umbraco 7: Embed youtube videos property

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I want to make a property that takes a YouTube video URL and returns the embed URL or such. What is the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that Umbraco allows you to do out of the box via the RTE. There are also packages that  will allow you to do this.

You need to spend a bit more quality time with the documentation and the forum http://our.umbraco.org/forum :)

Answer (score 1):

Well why not just have a text input to put the youtube video and just add it to the embed url because that is all that changes e.g.

youtube url:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxx

embed code:

iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxxxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen

so all that the use need to do is to add the id, much more easier that way :).